# Mock method and call through original callback

Tags: node.js, express, sinon

I have a method that I am trying to test that is invoked through a callback like so:

```
sessionService.getSession(req, res, req.query.state, handleSessionResponse);
```

Is there a way, using Sinon, to mock the `getSession` method *and* call through to the original callback (`handleSessionResponse`) in my function? In other words, I do not care about the implementation of `getSession` but I would like to delegate to the `handleSessionResponse` anyway to test it.

Here is a sample of the file:

```
handleSessionResponse(err, data, response) {
    // get to this point and make assertions
}

sessionService.getSession(req, res, req.query.state, handleSessionResponse);
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.

```
const sinon = require('sinon')
const { mockReq, mockRes } = require('sinon-express-mock')

let request = {
   query:{
        state:{}
   }
}
const req = mockReq(request)
const res = mockRes()

sinon.stub(sessionService, 'getSession').callsFake((req, res, req.query.state, callback) => {
    callback(null, {}, {})
});
```

callback should call your original handleSessionResponse